# WinForms (Infragistics Controls) - Deploying tabs from right to left and changin RibbonGroup size

Tags: winforms, infragistics

I'm using ultraToolbarsManager (by Infragistics) and I'm facing 2 problems:
1. I can't find out how to deploy the tabs from right to left.
2. I want to "stretch" one of 2 RibbonGroups to cover the entire Ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

Right to Left support for NetAdvantage for Windows Forms is a feature request and you should contact Infragistics for this.  Note that I am not sure if the Office UI Guidelines allow this.  For #2 regarding stretching a group, the Office UI Guidelines require that the width of each group be determined by the width of the controls within the group.

Answer (score 0):

```
If SystemDefaultLanguage = "ar-KW" Then

Dim label1 As New LabelTool("label1")
Me.uToolbarsManager.Tools.Add(label1)
label1.SharedProps.Caption = ""
Me.uToolbarsManager.Toolbars("Toolbar").Tools.InsertTool(0, "label1")
Me.uToolbarsManager.Toolbars("Toolbar").Tools.InsertTool(1, "Help")
Me.uToolbarsManager.Toolbars("Toolbar").Tools.InsertTool(2, "Print")
Me.uToolbarsManager.Toolbars("Toolbar").Tools.InsertTool(3, "Preview")
Me.uToolbarsManager.Toolbars("Toolbar").Tools("Print").InstanceProps.IsFirstInGroup = True
Me.uToolbarsManager.Toolbars("Toolbar").Tools("label1").SharedProps.Spring = True
Me.uToolbarsManager.Toolbars("Toolbar").Tools("label1").SharedProps.Width = 710
Me.uToolbarsManager.RightAlignedMenus = DefaultableBoolean.True

End If
```